# Error when running script in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I created a script to do a simple copy and sort and am receiving an error message.

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

Below is a jpg of the debug report

I ran the Debug and receiving the following message.

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 5, file "script1")Dismiss

The line `var rng1=sht.getRange('A1:C27');` is highlighted which does not show on the jpg.

[image: Debug report]

Comment: Do you have a sheet named 2scripts?

Comment: You could try changing the second line of your code to: var sht = ss.getActiveSheet();

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your script to this:

```
function script1()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var sht=ss.getSheetByName('2scripts');
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng1=sht.getRange('A1:C27');
  var rng2=sht.getRange('E1:G27');
  rng1.copyTo(rng2);
  rng2.sort([{column: 6, ascending: false}]);
}

function script2()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var sht=ss.getSheetByName('2scripts');
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng2=sht.getRange('E1:G27');
  rng2.sort([{column: 7, ascending: false}]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your posted code. I think from looking at your example that your code is not saved. Save it and run it again.

Comment: Good Answer. I never thought about that.